# IntelliJ IDEA - Java instrumentation premain gets called twice when directly run inside IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, instrumentation, javaagents

For some reason the `premain` of my Java Agent is executed twice when I run a program inside of IDEA and add the Agent jar via the IDEA VM options:

I have the following sample program and added the Java Agent in IDEA via
`Run Configuration` -> `VM options`: `-javaagent:/path/to/agent/MyJavaAgent.jar`

```
package com.example;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The `MyJavaAgent.jar` has the following structure:

```
.
├── com
│   └── example
│       └── MyJavaAgent.class
└── META-INF
    └── MANIFEST.MF
```

MyJavaAgent.java

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class MyJavaAgent {
    private static int callCount = 0;
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        callCount++;
        System.out.println("premain call " + callCount);
    }
}
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.example.MyJavaAgent
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix: true
```

When I run the sample `Test.main()` I get the following output:

```
> Task :Test.main()
premain call 1
premain call 2
Hello World!
```

When I run the program without IDEA everything looks like expected:

```
> java -javaagent:/path/to/agent/MyJavaAgent.jar com.example.Test
premain call 1
Hello World!
```

Can someone explain what is happening here? Is that an IDEA bug?

I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 (Ultimate Edition), Build #UI-193.6911.18`

Comment: Does the issue occur if you [disable gradle run delegation](https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you! That indeed fixes the issue. So it seems to be some Gradle issue? Maybe something related to gradle itself running on the JVM?

Comment: Please try running your app via Gradle per https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-run-java-main and see if you have the same issue in the command line. There may be some issue with IntelliJ IDEA related to how it handles running the app via Gradle. It generates the custom task code to run your app, so first the agent can be called by Gradle and then by your app.

Comment: Using the application plugin (item 3. on the baeldung link) and adding the agent via `applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-javaagent:/path/to/agent/MyJavaAgent.jar"]` in my `build.gradle` the premain is only executed once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be related to how IntelliJ IDEA is starting your class via Gradle by generating the task on the fly.

The workaround is to [disable the run delegation to Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7Sk.png).

I've [reported a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235974) that you can follow for updates.